# Asymptotic bounds for $T(n)=T(n-2)+n$

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I am trying to figure out how to find the Asymptotic bounds for $T(n)=T(n-2)+n$ and I am pretty sure that I need to use the substitution method. I have what I believe is a proof  using the [Subtract and Conquer](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Esaunders/notes/recurrence-relations.pdf) method, which was not a method that has been covered yet.

#### Subtract and Conquer

$T(n)=T(n-2)+n$

Subtract and Conquer: $T(n) = aT(n-b) + f(n)$ when $n > 1$

$T(n) = [O(n^k),\ if\ a < 1\ |\ O(n^{k+1}),\ if\ a = 1\ |\ O(n^{ka^{n/b}}),\ if\ a >1]$

$a = 1,\ b = 2,\ k = 1$

$T(n) = O(n^{1+1})$

$\equiv T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^2)\ \blacksquare$

#### I tried to formulate one by expanding the recurrence, but I just don't know where to go after doing so

$T(n)=T(n-2)+n$

$T(n-2) = [T(n-4)+(n-2)]+n$

$ = T(n-4)+2n-2$

$T(n-4) = [T(n-6)+(n-4)]+2n-2$

$=T(n-6)+3n-6$

$T(n-6) = [T(n-8)+(n-6)+3n-6$

$=T(n-8)+4n-12$

Substitute k:  $\ T(n-2k)+kn-c_1$

#### And then with the substitution method:

$T(n)=T(n-2)+n$

Assume: $\ T(1) = \Theta(1)$

Guess: $O(n^2)$

Assume: $\ T(k) \leq c \cdot k^2\ $ for $k<n$

$ \leq c(n-2)^2+n$

$ = cn^2+(-4)+n$

$ = cn^2-(4-n)\ $

$ (4-n) \geq 0\ for\ n\geq4$

$ T(n) = O(n^2)\ \blacksquare$

I'm not even sure if I'm in the ballpark here.  If someone has a good article to read or some advice I would really appreciate it.

Comment: did you try GFs? It may get a bit messy though

Comment: Sorry what is "GFs"?

Comment: generating functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even $n=2k$,

$$T(2k)=T(2(k-1))+2k$$
or
$$T'(k)=T'(k-1)+2k$$
which is a simple first order recurrence on $k$ (sum of integers), and

$$T(n)=T(2k)=2\frac{k(k+1)}2+T_0=\frac n2(\frac n2+1)+T_0.$$

For odd $n=2k+1$,

$$T(2k+1)=T(2(k-1)+1)+2k+1$$
or
$$T'(k)=T'(k-1)+2k+1$$
which is a simple first order recurrence on $k$ (sum of odd integers), and

$$T(n)=T(2k+1)=k(k+2)+T_1=\frac{(n-1)(n+3)}4+T_1.$$

Hence whatever the initial values, $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{T(n)}{n^2}=\dfrac14$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:
$T(n)={1\over 2}n.{\left(n+1\right)}-3+T(1)+T(2)-T(n-1)$ for $n=3,4,5,...$

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand enough to see the relation between this and my problem. Why $T(n)=\frac{1}{2}n$?

Comment: I just did some calculations to find relation between T(n) & T(n-1) like usual recursive functions hope you will be more happy with it instead of your original relation. It's easy to reach this.